# Error al intentar guardar captura de pantalla

Tags: android

Estoy intentando guardar una captura de pantalla al momento de dar clic en un boton, pero me marca un error cuando presiono ese boton. 
el codigo que uso para tomar la foto y guardarla.

```
  public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

y este es el codigo al presionar el boton

```
 public void salir (View view){
    Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
    saveBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Este es el mensaje de error

```
E/GREC: /storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
        at com.example.oscar.app.consulta.saveBitmap(consulta.java:72)
        at com.example.oscar.app.consulta.salir(consulta.java:86)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72) 
        at com.example.oscar.app.consulta.saveBitmap(consulta.java:72) 
        at com.example.oscar.app.consulta.salir(consulta.java:86) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: en tu error te dice: EACCES (Permission denied) Tenes que agregarle permisos en tu AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Agrega el permiso en el AndroidManifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**EDICION**

Como estas utilizando android 6.0, los modelos o mas bien el flujo de los permisos en estas versiones o porteriores cambiaron. Ahora es el usuario el que decide de dar los permisos UNA vez que la aplicacion de ejecuta. Antiguamente cuando el  usuario instalaba la app avisaba y mostraba a que permisos tenia que dar permisos para ejecutarla, ahora bien, hoy con estas versiones una vez que el usuario ejecuta la aplicacion Y es necesario utilizar dichos permisos la aplicacion lo deberia preguntar (eres tu quien debe controlar esto mediante codigo). Lo que tu debes hacer es primero verificar la version del android donde se esta ejecutando la app y si es una posterior o igual a 6 verificar dichos permisos. Te dejo un post donde explican mucho mejor esto y podras resolverlo. En este post podrás ver este o otros permisos que necesites acceder en tu app.

[Permisos Android](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal)

Comment: ya lo hice pero me sigue mandando el error. En que parte del Manifest tiene que estar este permiso? porque lo coloque hasta el final de application

Comment: Dentro de las etiquetas <manifest> que version de android estas ocupando para probar?

Comment: version de android 6.0

Comment: Edite mi respuesta!

Comment: según entendí tengo que hacer un método con los permisos que voy a solicitar. Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Exactamente, desde la version 6.0 en adelante hay codigo que te ayuda a verificar los permisos, puedes ver la documentación para ver cada permiso

Comment: Otra duda, referente a lo mismo. El código que use  guarda la imagen en memoria externa, según leí, pero si quiiero guardarlo dentro de la memoria interna en tengo que dar permisos igual? y tambien que linea de texto se tiene que cambiar para guardarlo internamente (quiero guardar en la galeria del telefono)

Comment: Nunca he guardado una imagen dentro de la galeria de forma nativa, pero de manera hibrida creo que no es necesario permisos para acceder a guardar en la galeria pero puedes buscar codigo de ejemplo en los buscadores hay muchos!

Answer (score -1):

Esto esta relacionado a la versión Android 6.0 y  **no es suficiente con agregar este permiso en el `AndroidManifest.xml`**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Propongo este método para que lo llames al iniciar tu aplicación y de esta forma configures el permiso:

```
private void checkWritePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para enviar escribir.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para enviar Escribir!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Me pregunto quien en su juicio dio -1, si se tiene esta excepción: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) es causada por falta de permisos que en Android 6.0 no solamente se definen en AndroidManifest.xml